# how can i read with jquery a file csv that has been uploaded with html form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, csv

I am trying to read a csv file with jquery. I have passed the file with input tag of html but i am having some problems to read it. Below the code that i have written.

HTML code:

```
<div id="insertCSV" class = "formblacktransparent">
                                <input id="csv" type="file" accept=".csv" class="form-control"  placeholder="Insert csv"> </input>
                                <button type="button" class="log-btn" id="confCsv"> Confirm </button>

                            </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#confCsv").click(function(data){
                var input = document.getElementById('csv');
                var file = input.files[0];
                alert(file[0]);
                 var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.readAsDataURL(data);
                alert(fr);

                });
```

I don 't understand if in this way the file has been uploaded and how i can accede to it.
Any ideas? thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I write below the code that i have used to resolve my problem. I hope it can be useful. Hello!

```
document.querySelector("#confCsv").addEventListener('click', function() {
                if(document.querySelector("#csv").files.length == 0) {
                alert('Error : No file selected');
                return;
                }

                 // first file selected by user
                var file = document.querySelector("#csv").files[0];

                 // perform validation on file type & size if required

                 // read the file
                 var reader = new FileReader();

                // file reading started
                reader.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
                console.log('File reading started');
                });

                 // file reading finished successfully
                 reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                   // contents of file in variable     
                 var text = e.target.result;
                  var row =  text.split('\n');



                  row.forEach(function(e) {

                  var datiGiornalieri = e.split(';');
                socket.emit('parameterRegistrationFile', {ID: patientID, paramdata: datiGiornalieri[0], parametername: 'alfa',parametervalue: datiGiornalieri[1] });

                  });
    });

                reader.readAsText(file);
    });
```